# How do I implement fallback language concept in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have a scenario having different languages records, what i need is to get all data in individual rows, if some data is not in required language then next default language came into the action for that record and so on.

[image: Sample DB]

```
declare @LanguageId int = 3
    select * from Purpose where LanguageId=(CASE WHEN @LanguageId = 1 THEN CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT PurposeId
    FROM Purpose
    WHERE LanguageId = @LanguageId) THEN @LanguageId WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT PurposeId
    FROM Purpose
    WHERE LanguageId = 2) THEN 2 ELSE 3 END WHEN @LanguageId = 2 THEN CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT PurposeId
    FROM Purpose
    WHERE LanguageId = @LanguageId) THEN @LanguageId WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT PurposeId
    FROM Purpose
    WHERE LanguageId = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 3 END WHEN @LanguageId = 3 THEN CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT PurposeId
    FROM Purpose
    WHERE LanguageId = @LanguageId) THEN @LanguageId WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT PurposeId
    FROM Purpose
    WHERE LanguageId = 2) THEN 2 ELSE 1 END END)
```

I have make query to do so and working fine, i am looking for an alternate optimized query for same. Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What defines the "*next*" default LanguageId?

Comment: Maybe something like `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY PurposeId HAVING LanguageId = MIN( LanguageId )` would work. This gives one record for each PurposeId containing whatever LanguageId is the lowest for that PurposeId.

Comment: by "next default language" i mean priority of language. e.g. Lang1 is prior to Lang2 and Lang3 and Lang2 is prior to Lang3 and so on..

Comment: I thought so. Try the group by from above.

Comment: hmm your suggestion is good but,as i said there is required language. Suppose user want to see data in Lang3 and data is only available in Lang2, then we need to check first in  Lang3 then in Lang1 and then Lang2. So there is lot of backtracking there.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT
p1.PurposeId, MIN( ISNULL( p2.LanguageId, p1.LanguageId ) ) AS LanguageId
FROM Purpose p1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Purpose p2 on p1.PurposeId = p2.PurposeId AND p2.LanguageId = :desiredLanguage
GROUP BY p1.PurposeId
```

Yields the `desiredLanguage` if there is an entry, or else the lowest available LanguageId for the each PurposeId.